# Is tension a resistive force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

The normal force is thought of as being the resistive force that prevents two objects from occupying the same space. In a similar fashion, is it acceptable to think of *tension* as being the resistive force that opposes the stretching of a string, rope, or cable?

Answer (score 1):

Tension is a response to some other stimuli like an external force or perturbation. On the microsopic scale, it may be due to metallic bonding or crystal lattice structure that gives rise to these forces. You can think of it as being an inertial property of the object. Any change(eg: external stimuli) is prevented by this inertial property, which tends to maintain its current state.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar if you like that answer, then accept it.   My way of looking at tension is as the opposite of compression.   A pull instead of a push.   The usual normal force is a force of compression.

Comment: Oh, that's also a nice way of looking at it. I do like that answer and so I will stick with what Lelouch has said :)

Comment: This does not seem quite correct. Tension is not like inertia. It does not tend to maintain the current state of the object. If a mass is moving and you try to slow it down it resists. But if a string is extended in tension and you try to shorten it, it does not resist you it *assists* you.

Comment: If this answer describes an acceptable definition of the word *tension*, then the word is ambiguous and must be defined when used.  Another common definition of *tension* is something like "a force that pulls on an object".  Consider a rope connected to a box.  The rope applies a tension force to the box.  In this definition, tension is not an intrinsic property of the rope.  If the boundary of the system divides the rope, then one part of the rope applies a tension force to the other.  The definition in this answer sounds to me more like *elasticity*.